# I installed ESM and now I want to remove it

Tags: node.js, npm

I used the terminal and npm to install ESM, `npm install esm`, but now I would like to remove it.

I tried `npm uninstall esm` but it seems like it's still there.

I was trying to use the ES6 syntax with express, but it's an extra headache.

anyway TD;LR, every time I try starting my app using node index.js I get this error:

```
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3000
}
```

I tried using the killall -9 node, but that just stops the local server once, and when I start it again and stop it, the error returns.

Comment: You're not shutting down the server correctly, or have something else running on that port.

Comment: ctrl + Z is what I use to shut down the app. it's never been an issue before, it started happening after installing esm.

Comment: ^Z doesn't try to kill an app, it sends a `SIGTSTP `. It's suspended.

Comment: Ah! You’re right. It’s ^C. It’s always been ^C. I think I did ^Z by mistake and saw the change. It does send a SIGTSTP. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 0):

in case of yarn, .yarnrc and .yarn.js got created which were referring to esm module despite me removing esm. Had to delete these two file to make it work.